# Algolia : How to change group title in Algolia Search Results

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I would like to change the Group Title (**Products**) depending on the JavaScript variable available on the website.

Using Algolia Autocomplete search with WordPress.

I have attached the screenshot showing the title that I want to be changed.[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Comment: @DanielOcando Thank you for pointing out. Let me alter the post.